# Fundamental Group of Klein Bottle acts on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

It is well know that the Fundamental Group of the Klein Bottle can be defined (up to isomorphism) as the group with two generator and one relation

$$BS(1,-1)=\langle a,b: bab^{-1}=a^{-1}\rangle $$

In Algebraic Topology this fundamental group is defined as the group $G$ of homeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ generate by $f,g:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ where:

$$f(x,y)=(x,y+1), g(x,y)=(x+1,1-y)$$

I want to find a linear action of $G$ on $\mathbb{R}$, e.g, an operation $"\cdot":G\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:

1.- $g\cdot(x_{1}+x_{2})=g\cdot x_{1}+g\cdot x_{2}$

2.- $g_{1}\cdot (g_{2}\cdot x)=(g_{1}g_{2})\cdot x$

3.- $1_{G}\cdot x=x$,

for all $g,g_{1},g_{2}\in G$ and $x, x_{1}, x_{2}\in \mathbb{R}$.

My motivation: find a solvable notnilpotent group $G$ acting linearly on a finite dimensional vector space $M$ such that
$H^{0}(G,M)=0$ but $H^{k}(G,M)\neq 0$ for some $k$.

Comment: As to your motivation from group cohomology, your example will work, or you can instead take $G = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ acting by multiplication by $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Any one-dimensional representation of this group, will, as for any group, factor through its abelianization, which is $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Concretely, we can have $b$ act by multiplication by any non-zero scalar, and $a$ act by multiplication by $-1$ (we could also have $a$ acting trivially), and these are all the representations.

Comment: Do you mean that we can define $a\cdot x=-x$ and  $b\cdot x=x$  and then extends the action for any $g\in G$?

Comment: @JoséLuisCamarilloNava yes, exactly. Or $b \cdot x = \lambda x$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^\times$.

Comment: Note that to give an action of $G$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is the same as to give a map $G \to \mathbb{R}^\times$.

Comment: Excusme but: are you sure that defining $b\cdot x =x$ and $a\cdot x=-x$ do you actually get a linear action of $G$ over $\mathbb{R}$?  I've had troubles to proof the Property Number 2 of the definition of linear action. I know that each element $g\in G$ can express in the form $g=a^{n}b^{m}$ where $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$. How to define $g\cdot x$ for an arbitrary $g\in G$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @JoséLuisCamarilloNava if you have a group given by generators and relations, you just need to check that the relations act like the identity to be sure the putative action is well-defined

Comment: Yes, I know that, but how do you proof the Property 2 in ditail?

Comment: @JoséLuisCamarilloNava property two just says that the map to $\mathbb{R}^\times = \text{Aut}(\mathbb{R})$ is a group homomorphism. To give a homomorphism in terms of generators and relations, you just need to say where the generators go and check that the relations map to $1$.

Comment: Why did you say that my example works as my motivation for cohomology ? Acording with my computations  $H^{1}(G,\mathbb{R})=0$. Am I right?

Comment: @JoséLuisCamarilloNava perhaps I spoke too soon! My vague thought was that the Klein bottle is a $K(G, 1)$ so the group cohomology of $G$ ought to be the first cohomology of the Klein bottle. I didn't compute with cocycles, though.

Comment: So...it is not easy to find a solvable notnilpotent group $G$ acting linearly on a finite dimensional vector space $M$ such that $H^{0}(G,M)=0$ but $H^{k}(G,M)\neq 0$ for some $k$?

Comment: @JoséLuisCamarilloNava well I think Hˆ1 in this case is $\mathbb{R}$, no ?

Comment: Well... $H^{1}(G,\mathbb{R})=Der(G,\mathbb{R})/Ider(G,\mathbb{R})$. Working computations on $ba=a^{-1}b$, every $\psi\in Der(G,\mathbb{R})$ must to satisfy $\psi(b)=0$. On the other hand, the equation $\psi(a)=a\cdot x-x$ has a solution $x$. Thus, $\psi\in Ider(G,\mathbb{R})$ and so $H^{1}(G,\mathbb{R})=0$....Am I right?

Comment: Are you agree with my compute of $H^{1}(G,\mathbb{R})=0$ ?